# Adding a ViewPager inside a NavigationDrawer

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-viewpager

I'm developing an Android app from "Navigation Drawer Activity" Template.

In this template, each click on a navigation menu item opens a Fragment.

The first fragment is a simple fragment with `TextView`.
The second fragment is a fragment that contains a `TabLayout` and a `ViewPager` to navigate to other fragments.

My only problem is that since the TabLayout and the ViewPager are created in the layout's fragment, so not at the same time as the actionBar, I have a shadow between the actionBar and the TabLayout. The selected fragment indicator is also a bit strange.

[image]

**MainActivity layout**:

```
<com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:theme="@style/Theme.BodetTag.AppBarOverlay">

    <androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize"
        app:popupTheme="@style/Theme.BodetTag.PopupOverlay">
        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="center_vertical"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            tools:ignore="UseCompoundDrawables">

            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="50dp"
                android:layout_height="50dp"
                android:src="@drawable/bodet_icon_mini"
                android:contentDescription="@string/bodet_icon" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/title"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:minHeight="?actionBarSize"
                android:padding="@dimen/appbar_padding"
                android:text="@string/app_name"
                android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.Widget.AppCompat.Toolbar.Title" />

        </LinearLayout>
    </androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar>

</com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout>
```

**Fragment layout**:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".ui.tag.TagFragment">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/text_tag"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:textAlignment="center"
        android:textSize="20sp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <com.google.android.material.tabs.TabLayout
        android:id="@+id/tabs"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
        android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:tabIndicatorColor="@color/white"
        app:tabSelectedTextColor="@color/white" />

    <androidx.viewpager.widget.ViewPager
        android:id="@+id/view_pager"
        android:paddingTop="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"/>
</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have partially found the answers to my problems.

First of all, the TabLayout was too high. So I simply deleted the following line in the TabLayout layout:

```
android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize"
```

Then, to remove the shadow between the actionBar and the tabLayout, several solutions are possible:

- Add the following line in the AppBarLayout (This will remove the shadow for all fragments of the application):

  ```
  app:elevation="0dp"
  ```
- Add the following line in the fragment that contains the TabLayout:

  ```
  (activity as AppCompatActivity).supportActionBar!!.elevation = 0f
  ```

For the moment, only the first method works but the second method is more accurate.

Answer (score 0):

**In Fragment Layout :**

Try Changing the ViewPager height from match_parent to 550dp (or height suitable to you, like 450dp or 455dp).

Don't use match_parent as it will also cover your TabLayout.

Please tell me whether its working or not. Thank you